# Low Memory dtypes allowing nan

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

I'm trying to identify a way to store a series of int in a dataframe columns, allowing missing values.

As known, if exist at least a np.nan in a series, his dtype is automatically changed to float 64; in my case this is a problem since i'm handling big tables.

Does exist a way to maintain low memory dtypes (as bool, int), allowing missing values?

Thanks

Comment: No, there is no way to represent missing values using ints or bools. You could use a sparse matrix to conserve space, the other thing is do you need these NaN values?